# If Socrates time travelled to the 21st century, would he still face the same fate?

Tags: plato, society, socrates, contemporary-philosophy, platonism

I believe that the Athenian community and authority did not appreciate his philosophy and political view.

Sometimes, I tell himself that they just didn't know his worth as he was way ahead of his time.

Yet, saying that he's ahead of his time implies that there's a time in the future that suits his philosophy. Would that time be now, or aren't we ready for another Socrates yet?

However, would he received any differently by our community and authorities than the way Athenian ones did?

I'm also curious what beliefs would contemporary Socrates question?

Thank you!

Comment: [Socrates Through Time](https://existentialcomics.com/comic/395). But, you have to bear in mind, [The "Apology"](https://existentialcomics.com/comic/100)

Comment: @Michael: You know Socrates was executed for his philosophy right?

Comment: He would be banned from all philosophy forums. He had to drink the virtual juice.

Comment: @CriglCragl -- This I know. The point was that these days information is usually controlled in a "soft" manner; so rather than physically taking out the tongue, other methods of rightthink are employed.

Answer (score 1):

Dostoevsky considers a similar situation in The Brothers Karamazov: *What would happen if Jesus Christ came to visited us*? You can read it [here](https://gutenberg.org/files/8578/8578-h/8578-h.htm). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Grand_Inquisitor) describes the influence of this tale. I tend to agree with Dostoevsky: no society is prepared to deal with a fully developed personality. It will always disrupt the status quo.